# Keeping Hover-Over Text Active When Cell Is Locked

Tags: excel

Quick question. I have headers in my Excel spreadsheet that have hover-over text through Data Validation --> Input Message. My VBA script that runs dynamically may lock some of these cells, and that makes the hover-over disabled (because it's really not a hover-over, it's actually a cell select).  Is there any way to allow the User to hover over a cell that is locked and still see the hover-over text?  Thanks!

[image]